# Evaluate the value of integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$I = \int_{1/3}^1 {x\left\lfloor {1/x} \right\rfloor dx} $
. Where$\lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer function less than or equal to $x$.

I've evaluated $I = \int_{1/3}^1 {\left\lfloor {1/x} \right\rfloor dx} $ whose
value is $5/6$ but, I'm unable to find the value of $I$.
I tried and apply Integration by parts method but of no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ought to break the integral up, treating the greatestint(x) function as a coefficient. The greatest integer function of 1/x between $1/3<x<1$ is 1 on $1/2<x<1$ and 2 on $1/3<x<1/2$, so break it in half and evaluate the integral of f(x)=x from $1>x>1/2$, then add two times the integral of f(x)=x from $1/2<x<1/3$.

Comment: :there should be a change in last line.